# Testing a Rails Application with Multiple Databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, testing, activerecord

I have a rails application which uses two databases in *production* environment, `Users` and `Process`. The `Users` model uses this customized `ActiveRecord` class:

```
class UserActiveRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection "#{Rails.env}_users_db"
end

class User < UserActiveRecord
    ...
```

Notice that the connection to a specific database is established depending on the environment. To simplify things, in the *testing* environment I have a single database with all the tables from the two production databases, and my `database.yml` file looks something like this:

```
test:
    adapter: postgresql
    database: db_test
    host: localhost
    pool: ...
    timeout: ...
    username: ...
    password: ...

test_users_db:
    adapter: postgresql
    database: db_test  <--- Notice that this is the same database only in test env
    host: localhost
    pool: ...
    timeout: ...
    username: ...
    password: ...
```

The application runs fine in production, but when I run any test that refers to the `User` class, the test blocks at the exact point where `User` is used and nothing happens, it doesn't show any error, it doesn't exit, it just keeps waiting.

I double-checked and the table `USERS` exists in the test database, in fact if I delete it manually I get the error that the table doesn't exists and when I create it again I get the same behavior reported in the previous paragraph.

I don't have a clue why this is happening, any idea on how can I solve this issue? or how can I debug it so that I can get to the root of the problem? If it helps, I'm using Ruby 1.9.3, Ruby on Rails 3.2.19 and PostgreSQL 9.3.5; any additional details will be posted as required.

Comment: We've been stumped by this problem for some time now. Any Ruby expert that can lend a hand? say, @ChrisJester-Young ;-) ?

Comment: Is your postgres instance configured to allow more than 1 connection? Even though the databases are the same in the test environment rails will almost certainly be creating another connection to the database because of the two different database configurations. Also worth checking it supports enough connections for both pool sizes.

Comment: Try `establish_connection "#{Rails.env}_users_db" unless Rails.env.test?` to confirm this line is the culprit. It might be something else is going on.

Comment: @Shadwell I tested the connection using the User.connected? method and it returns true, do you think this is enough?

Comment: @javier I'm not entirely sure to be honest. It'd definitely be worth checking the configuration for postgres as well. Maybe your connection pool is hitting the limit as more connections happen. It's not definitely the problem though - just a hunch.

Comment: @javier What test framework are you using? Could you post the config for your test (something like spec_helper.rb etc..)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly stating that it's the same database? Try editing your database.yml file to look like this:

```
test: &default_test
    adapter: postgresql
    database: db_test
    host: localhost
    pool: ...
    timeout: ...
    username: ...
    password: ...

test_users_db:
    <<: *default_test
```